# How do I declare an argument for a function of a templated nested class type?

Tags: c++, function, templates, nested, arguments

I have a container class like so:

```
template<class T>
class MyList
{
    class iterator
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Now I want to define a `find` function like so:

```
template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator find (
    MyList<T>::iterator first, 
    MyList<T>::iterator last, 
    const T& val)
{
    ...
}
```

This does not compile. How do I declare function arguments of type `MyList<T>::iterator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify the argument type with `typename`, to let the compiler know that you're referring to a type.

```
template<class T>
typename MyList<T>::iterator find (
    typename MyList<T>::iterator first, 
    typename MyList<T>::iterator last, 
    const T& val)
{
    ...
}
```